# best way to linking android application to another one

Tags: android, xml, google-play

I have an android application and I want to add "in addition to banner, interstitial" link to another application is mine, **it seems that I should build something like banner by my myself, isn't it?**

I'm seeking for good manner to do that like "Google Play Badge" but it generates HTML code not XML,apart from "Google Play Badge", **what's the best technique to linking to my applications?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob has a program called house ad, with is ads that point from one app you own to an other and it is completely free. You can find instruction on how to use it on the links.

https://www.google.com/ads/admob/index.html

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1619751?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start